# In Zend Framework 1.12, how to avoid getting an action?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I have an action method that only triggers when post data to it.
So I add some logic code to prevent the get request.

```
public function myAction()
{
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
        {
            echo "No get!";
            die();
        }
        else
        {
          //some other codes
        }
}
```

It works.
But I have to write these code snippet to many action method. It looks so redundant.

So, is there a better way to implement it like the above code?

Comment: you can add your code in your layout file which will be called for every action, and you can check your condition and also can pass some data along if you like.

Comment: some actions only need post request,some need get request.So can't do it in layout file I think.

Answer (score 1):

Add  this method to your controller

```
public function preDispatch(){
    if(!$this->_request->isPost() and in_array($this->_request->getParam('action'), array('action1', 'action2'))){
        exit('only post');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its too late to answer this question now but hope it will help someone else.

If you want to do this for just one controller then your better off using the controllers _init() method as shown below.

```
public function _init() {
    if(!$this->getRequest()->isPost()){
       //The request is not post. Do what you like.
    }
}
```

If you want the same thing for multiple controllers you can create a frontController plugin like this.

```
class Application_Plugin_Request extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
        if(!$request->$isPost()){
                //The request is not post. Do what you like.   
            }
    }
}
```

Add this method to your Bootstrap class for activate the plugin.

```
protected function _initPlugins(){
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_Request(), 17); 
}
```